# GoLang WebCrawling remove empty tags

Tags: go, goquery

I am trying to crawl web, and few cases my HTML looks like this and includes `\n` & `\t`.

```html
<article>
    <div></div>
    <p>
        <br/>\n</p>\n\t
    <p><span></span></p>
</article>
```

How would I remove tags in some cases I have `\n` or `\t` I need to strip that as well.

1. Stripping all \n so that tag would become empty.
2. If it is empty its parent would also be empty, which also needs to be strip recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want.

```
re, _ := regexp.Compile("(<.*?>|\n|\t|\\\\n|\\\\t)")
rep := re.ReplaceAllString(`<article>
<div></div>
<p>
        <br/>\n</p>\n\t
<p><span></span></p>
</article>`, "")
fmt.Println(rep)
```

Or, the following code only removes empty Tags.

```
func RemoveTags(html string) string {
    re, _ := regexp.Compile("<[^>/]+></[^>]+>")
    rep := re.ReplaceAllString(html, "")
    if rep != html {
        return RemoveTags(rep)
    }
    return rep
}

re, _ := regexp.Compile("(\n|\t|\\\\n|\\\\t|<[^/>]+/>)")
        rep := re.ReplaceAllString(`<article>123
        <div></div>
        <p>
                <br/>\n</p>\n\t
        <p><span></span></p>
</article>`, "")
fmt.Println(RemoveTags(rep))
```

Result:

```
<article>123</article>
```